# Make the sheet background transparent in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In `iOS 16.4` you can make the `.sheet` background transparent, is there any workaround to get the same behavior in previous versions?

In iOS 16.4 applying `.presentationBackground(Color.clear)` makes the `.sheet` background transparent.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showFormView){
    FormView()
        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        .presentationBackground(Color.clear)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can do it by making your `FormView` background transparent, rather than the newer `.presentationBackground`. So try modifying your FormView directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: This will not work with versions older than iOS 16.

Comment: Does this help to answer your question: [stackflow question from 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745084/how-can-i-make-a-background-color-with-opacity-on-a-sheet-view)