SwiftUI Native translucent background
I want a VStack to have a translucent background and other apps or wallpaper to appear behind it, like the sidebars of Apple apps, like the Safari tab area and the Xcode files area.
Instead of Color.purple, I want to I have a translucent background.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(content: {
            VStack(content: {
                Color.green
            })
            VStack(content: {
                Color.purple
            })
        })
        .frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            idealWidth: 100,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            idealHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .center
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Have a look at this SO post/answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745084/how-can-i-make-a-background-color-with-opacity-on-a-sheet-view/63745596#63745596
Just replace UIViewRepresentable with NSViewRepresentable and use
view.window?.backgroundColor = .clear, works for me.
