# Is there a way that I can use to create a Dynamic Sheet Height using in SwiftUI (iOS14.7)?

Tags: ios, user-interface, swiftui, mobile, ios14

I tried this aproach https://stackoverflow.com/a/66925913/15450928 but is seems I can't center my graphical date and time picker.

Maybe someone has an idea about it.

This is what I use:

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditDataTime, content: {
            EditDateAndTimeView()
                .frame(height: 580)
                .clearModalBackground()
        })
```

Here is my current result: [image]
I need to create a Sheet with dynamic height for choosing a date and time and also have 2 buttons under this picker with a custom navigation bar.

The result should be something like this: [image]

Comment: It seems that on iOS 14.7 you reinvent what is supposed to work on iOS 16 out of the box, so I will just use:                 if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    EditDateAndTimeView()
                        .presentationDetents([.height(dataAndTimeSheetHeight)])
                } else {
                    EditDateAndTimeView()
                }